# How to optimize SQL Server Merge statement running with millions of records

Tags: sql-server, performance, merge

I use SQL Server 2014 and need to update a new added datetime type column in one table. There are two tables related (both have > 30 millions of records):

TableA:

```
CategoryID, itemID, dataCreated, deleted, some other string properties.
```

This table contains multiples records for each item with different `datecreated`.

TableB:

```
CategoryID, itemID, LatestUpdatedDate (This is the new added column)
```

both `categoryID` and `itemID` are part of an index on this table.

To update tableB's `LatestUpdatedDate` from table A on matched `CategoryID` and `ItemID`, I used the following merge statement:

```
merge [dbo].[TableB] with(HOLDLOCK) as t
using 
(
    select CategoryID,itemID, max(DateCreated) as LatestUpdatedDate 
    from dbo.TableA 
    where TableA.Deleted = 0
    group by CategoryID,itemID
) as s on t.CategoryID = s.CategoryID and t.itemID = s.itemID

when matched then
    update
    set t.LatestUpdatedDate = s.LatestUpdatedDate

when not matched then
    insert (CategoryID, itemID, LatestUpdatedDate)
    values (s.CategoryID, s.itemID)
```

Given the fact that millions of records in both table, How can I optimize this script? Or Is there any other way to update the table with better performance?

Note: This is a one-off script and DB is on live, there would be a trigger added to tableA against insert to update the date in tableB in the future.

Comment: The key questions are: do the changes need to be atomic? Is there a period were you can lock this table exclusively?If it doesn't need to be atomic then I would split it into seperate `update` and `insert` statements. That way you're breaking your work in half. I've been burnt by `merge` before, performance wise, so now I steer away from it. You can also use the `set rowcount` trick to just update smaller batches at a time rather than locking the entire table in one go.

Comment: I should mention that this is a live database, though I can certainly run the script during night/weekend when there is much less traffic. what kind of performance issue you have before with merge? I am not quiet sure how long it will take to execute this on this level tables. minutes, hours?

Comment: With merge the performance was with the `when not matched` part. You need to work out if the changes need to be atomic. That is: is it OK if the table just gets gradual changes made to it over say a few hours, or does the table need to be entirely updated in one go (for consistency). Will your application break if row y is updated but not row x? Note that this is going to be slow (no matter what way you do it) if you don't have indexes on the join columns. Adding indexes is not a table change that will break an application, and you can drop them afterwards.

Comment: How many rows are there in the subtable s``? How many in `TableA`? It might be worth dropping that into a table first. Also are you aware of wht `HOLDOCK` will do? Do you know if it will affect the application over the top?

Comment: Thanks Nick. The change doesn't need to be atomic as I won't enable the code related until data is ready.  Both tables got > 30 millions rows and tableA is about twice than tableB. `HOLDOCK` is used here to prevent concurrency issue as described from here:  [link](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx). I test with some local fake data with around 50 millions rows and the script completed within 10 min. Seems it is acceptable for an one-off operation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per [Optimizing MERGE Statement Performance](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879317(v=sql.105).aspx), the best you can do is:

- Create an index on the join columns in the source table that is unique and covering.
- Create a unique clustered index on the join columns in the target table.

You may get a performance improvement during `MERGE1` by creating an index on `TableA` on `(Deleted, CategoryID, itemID) INCLUDE(DateCreated)`. However, since this is a one-off operation, the resources (time, CPU, space) required to create this index probably won't offset the performance gains vis-a-vis running the query as-is and relying on your existing index.

Comment: yeah, as this is a one-off operation, I would avoid to make any change to the table itself. will it helpful if I split it into multiple merge with condition like categoryID<500, categoryID>500...

Comment: test with table with >50M rows which have index build and it takes about 2min to complete. seems fine. Thanks.

Comment: I have a question: the clustered index requires a sorted input, so it's possible that the query optimizer will do a sort operation that's really not the best thing to do with millions of records. Furthemore, the clustered index make the insert/update operation slower, even in the SQL preview. So, what's the benefit of the clustered index?

Comment: A clustered index specifies the order in which data is stored in a table. [**Most tables should have a carefully chosen clustered index unless a good reason exists for leaving the table as a heap.**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/heaps-tables-without-clustered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15). The database engine may be able to find (potentially) matching rows in the target table quicker, when the target table has a clustered index. Index seek is much faster than a full table scan.

Comment: Yes, `INSERT` and `UPDATE` data writes could be slower. However, most tables would have a clustered index already. When designing a clustered index, in mind the typical use cases for the table.